# How I can Monitor other application and resources from IBM WebSphere Application Server 7.0

Tags: web-server, unix, ibm, application-server

I have IBM WebSphere Application Server+ 7.0 , and I deploy many java application on this server , from other hand I have stand alone java application ( this application is financial application and pass the traffic " transaction " to Application deployed in WAS ) integrated with the application that deployed on application server .

Stop or restart IBM-WAS mean that stand alone server will pass the traffic and no application will receive the traffic so that many claims will be received .

I need a way to manage this stand alone application with deployment manager or write a bash script to control this case .

Summary : I have Application depend on other so that i need to control both .
A: Application Deployed on IBM-WAS
B:Stand alone application
if the process A is stopped process B should be stopped also .

Answer (score 0):

Your infrastructure setup sounds strange to me....

a.  What java app server does that particular application run?

b.  Why not use Websphere for that financial application also?

While you're on the right track as to what you need to do (a bash script to run stopserver on the WAS server, and whatever command to stop whatever java app server that runs the financial application), I'd highly suggest realigning your infrastructure to run only one type of java application server, whether it is Websphere or not; your setup is un-necessarily complex, in my opinion.

Comment: the java app doesn't use java application ( it is stand alone server , you can execute lonely ) .
we design it as stone alone because we buy it as separated product not with the package of the other application  ( This application related to POS Driver ) and have many specialization so we cannot deploy it on application server ( also to reduce the cost )